# Arbitrarily weakly forced oscillations

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators) we learn that a harmonic oscillator with eigenfrequency $\omega_0$ that is driven by an externally applied force $F(t) = F_0 \sin(\omega t)$ and thus obeys the equation

[image]

behaves in steady state like

[image]

where

[image]

and

[image]

Without external force, i.e. for $F_0 = 0$, the oscillator behaves freely like

$x(t) = A \sin(\omega_0 t)$

What I don't understand is, why this is not the limit of $x_{F_0}(t)$ for $F_0 \rightarrow 0$, which is $\equiv 0$.

The other way around: How can arbitrarily small external forces $F_0$ force the oscillator to oscillate with $\omega$, even though the internal forces letting it oscillate with $\omega_0$ might be much stronger?

Is it just because with $F_0 \rightarrow 0$ the time until steady state is reached goes to $\infty$? Is there a formula which relates this time to $F_0$?

Comment: Without exernatl force, the oscillator should be damped, no?

Comment: Your are right. But let's set $\zeta=0$.

Comment: No time for a complete answer, but the solution of the driven oscillator consists of two parts: $x(t)=x_{transient}+x_{steady state}$,  where $x_{steady state}$ is the solution you gave, i.e. the forced oscillation at the driving frequency and this part indeed goes to zero if $F_0\to 0$. The other term, $x_{transient}$ is a damped oscillatory motion and if $F_0\to 0$ this term goes to the normal non-driven solution of the damped oscillator. For equations see for instance http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscdr.html